# Uniqueness of the group with order 5

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove the uniqueness of the group G of order 5 up to isomorphism (i.e. G = $\{e,\ a,\ b,\ c,\ d\}$). So far I have shown that $\forall a\in\ G\ ,$ $\ a^2\neq e$ where $e$ is the identity element.

I need help showing that there is no non-identity element $a$ such that $e,\ a,\ a^2$ are distinct but $a^3=e$.

Next given $e,\ a,\ a^2\ a^3$ are distinct I need to show $a^4 \neq e$.

With the above, I need to conclude that given any non-identity element, $a$, the elements $e,\ a,\ a^2,\ a^3,\ a^4$ are distinct but $a^5$ is necessarily equal to $e$.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's Theorem? Or the fact that $a^{|G|} = e$ for all $a \in G$?

Comment: No on Lagrange's, I believe $a^{|G|} = e$ for all $a \in G$ is what we're trying to prove for |G| = 5 (perhaps not in general). It is mentioned that a relevant assumed fact is that in the multiplication table of any group, G, each element of G appears exactly once in each row and each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e, a, a^2$ are distinct and $a^3=e$, take $g\in G$ different from $e, a, a^2$. Then  $e, a, a^2, g, ga, ga^2$ are all distinct (verify!), which cannot happen because then you'd have at least 6 elements in $G$.

Do the same thing if $e, a, a^2, a^3$ are distinct and $a^4=e$, to conclude that you'd have at least 8 elements in $G$.

Therefore, $e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4$ are distinct (verify!). This forces $a^5=e$ because if it must be one of $e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4$ but cannot be a non-zero power of $a$ because that would imply that $a^k=e$ for $1\le k\le 4$ and we have seen this cannot happen.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you!